# how to emulate weight paint brush stroke using python?

Tags: python, animation, scripting, weight-painting

I need to emulate brush stroke in weight paint mode but I don't know how.
I am trying to use the code but error code says

> RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.paint.weight_paint.poll() failed,
> context is incorrect

it says strokes variable isn't defined properly but I don't know how to define it.
Do you know how?

```
import bpy

strokes =[ {
"name": "Null",
"is_start": True,
"location": (0,0,0),
"size": 1.0,
"time":0.0,
"pressure": 0.0,
"pen_flip":False,
"mouse":(0.0, 0.0) 
},]

bpy.ops.object.vertex_group_set_active(group='xx')
bpy.data.brushes['Lighten'].stroke_method = 'LINE'
bpy.ops.paint.weight_paint(stroke=strokes, mode='NORMAL')
```